# How to access multiple similar tag in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML which is as follows.

```
    <statuses type="array">
    <status>
    <created_at>Thu Oct 20 09:49:46 +0000 2011</created_at>
    <text>@pkprasad82  Hello</text>
    <entities>
    <user_mentions>
    <user_mention end="11" start="0">
    <id>133809164</id>
    <screen_name>pkpras</screen_name>
    <name>prav</name>
    </user_mention>
    </user_mentions>
    <urls/>
    <hashtags/>
    </entities>
    </status>
    <status>
    <created_at>Thu Oct 20 09:49:46 +0000 2011</created_at>
    <text>hello  Hello</text>
    <entities>
    <user_mentions>
    <user_mention end="11" start="0">
    <id>123456789</id>
    <screen_name>pkpras</screen_name>
    <name>pravin</name>
    </user_mention>
    </user_mentions>
    <urls/>
    <hashtags/>
    </entities>
    </status>
    <statuses>
```

I want to access  only "id" tag for both "status" tag in php.I do not want any other tag.
For Example
Id=133809164
Id=123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) like so:

```
<?php

// @Himanshu - Notice correction to final closing tag.

$xmlstr = '
<statuses type="array">
  <status>
    <created_at>Thu Oct 20 09:49:46 +0000 2011</created_at>
    <text>@pkprasad82  Hello</text>
    <entities>
      <user_mentions>
        <user_mention end="11" start="0">
          <id>133809164</id>
          <screen_name>pkpras</screen_name>
          <name>prav</name>
        </user_mention>
      </user_mentions>
      <urls/>
      <hashtags/>
    </entities>
  </status>
  <status>
    <created_at>Thu Oct 20 09:49:46 +0000 2011</created_at>
    <text>hello  Hello</text>
    <entities>
      <user_mentions>
        <user_mention end="11" start="0">
          <id>123456789</id>
          <screen_name>pkpras</screen_name>
          <name>pravin</name>
        </user_mention>
      </user_mentions>
      <urls/>
      <hashtags/>
    </entities>
  </status>
</statuses>';

$mydata = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* For each <user_mention> node, we echo a separate <id>. */
foreach ($mydata as $status) {
    foreach ($status->entities->user_mentions as $user_mention) {
        echo $user_mention->user_mention->id, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

The output produced in this case is:

```
133809164
123456789
```

Comment: I don't understand why the need of a double foreach when you can just retrieve what you need using a location path. Anyway this is a solution too.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: You're right - the SimpleXML package always uses a DOM parser, so there's no performance benefit to using the approach described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to retrieve this information. The location path to pass as parameter to the linked method is:

```
/statuses/status//id
```

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the selflessness and the honesty.